# What should the domain name be?

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes, beta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name photo.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

See [Joel's advice](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/):

> Here’s some of my advice on domain
> names.
>
> 1. Please don’t think that it’s necessary to use a domain name that
>    reflects something going wrong. We
>    picked the name “Stack Overflow”
>    because it has some meaning for real
>    programmers, not because it reflected
>    a bug or problem. “Super User” is just
>    as good a name. I get depressed by all
>    these suggestions of
>    “BurntChicken.com”,
>    “LostYarmulke.com”, and
>    “FallenArches.com” (for former owners
>    of McDonald’s franchises, of course).
> 2. Look for jargon that has meaning to the group of people you want to
>    attract. Insider jargon is the duck
>    call of insiders. Look at me! If I can
>    say “contributory negligence,” I must
>    be a real lawyer!
> 3. .coms are a million times better than other TLDs.
> 4. A domain name should be readable over the phone. Even on AT&T Wireless.
>    Tricky spellings are always a bad
>    idea. Similarly, dashes reek of
>    desperation.
> 5. Long names are not the end of the world. Using two or three words (or a
>    couple of digits) is a good way to
>    find available domains.

Comment: Other betas are using top-7 as a tag for the items in the "top 7" post linked at the top of each meta page.

Comment: Other betas are also making these Community Wikis.

Comment: "Other betas..." didn't your mom warn you about following what all the other little betas are doing?  But seriously: there's no separate rep here, so vote away as a poll; the editing feature of CW could be useful.

Answer (score 25):

http://depthoffield.com/

http://DepthOfField.com/

http://DepthofField.com/

http://Depth.of.Field.com/ :)

parked

Comment: I love this for the double entendre: not only is it a photo term but it also suggests the detail in the q&a going on.

Comment: +1 ditto on what Craig said

Comment: +1 a ditto here too

Comment: I really like applying the term, but – as a site name – "of" seems out of place.  How would you write it? "Depth of Field" and "DepthofField.com"?  "Depth Of Field" runs counter to some English style guides and just looks wrong to me.  I keep seeing "off" as a word in "depthoffield.com", too.

Comment: @Roger: Good point. I would have it written DepthOfField.com. It's not proper English as you mentioned, but then neither is running words together without spaces. Capitalizing the D, O, and F emphasizes the three separate words, and is very important to prevent the "off" problem you mention.

Comment: @Craig: The hugely dominant pattern on the web is lowercase domains (I expanded my own answer to touch on this), and I think "depthoffield.com" would naturally become what people use instead of "DepthOfField.com".  It just feels weird to call the site "Depth of Field" but change to "Of" in the domain.

Comment: @Roger: Even though the name "Depth of Field" is not "proper english", I do think it fits as a title. I don't think were looking for a fully, grammatically correct sentence like "In the Depth of Field" or anything like that...that just seems too lengthy for a site name.

Comment: @jrista: "Depth of Field" is fine; ".. Of .." is counter to conventional title casing.

Comment: @Roger: AAH! I misunderstood your original point. Totally agree!

Comment: I see this is very popular, but I strongly oppose it. Here's why: depth of field is fairly specialized jargon, and newbies won't know it, thus making the site less accessible to this (important IMO) audience. I believe there's tremendous value in putting the word "photo" in the domain name.

Comment: I know I'm biased since I've already suggested my own, but `depthoffield` looks like `depth off ield` to me, it's just not very readable. It reminds me too much of expert sexchange. I'm sure they would have loved to CamelCase it, but that's not the way people write things.

Comment: @Reid: it's tempting to go this way but it's not really necessary. Newbies will find the site through Google and understand what it is through the site's subtitle & FAQ. This is a pretty common practice in website naming today. For instance: "Flickr" is widely understood to be the big photo-sharing website, but it's name doesn't have anything to do with actual photography. (It's not even a real word). Another example: Google. Good content will make the name/brand work.

Comment: @Craig: I think it's unrealistic to pattern our naming choices after those of sites many orders of magnitude larger than us. A pessimistic reinterpretation of your statement is: *Good content will compensate for a poor name/brand.*

Comment: I like the sound of the term, but it doesn't look good in print.  In (high quality) printing, ffi is printed as a ligature. That makes the domain look like depth-offield-dot-com.

Comment: I like the pun, because I love puns, but I don't think it communicates expertise in photography.  Obsession over depth of field, to me, definitely has connotations of "just bought my first DSLR" rather than "I'm a guru".

Comment: Capitalizing the D, O and F while not normal does fit with the common DOF acronym.

Comment: This feels too broad and doesn't really ring of photography specifically.

Comment: Although I do like the term I don't encourage using it for the domain name due the readability and spelling issues already mentioned. Another negative point is that this name is three words long. Domain names consisting of one or two words just sound shorter and better when spoken out loud (compare hotmail.com vs depthoffield.com).

Comment: Feels gimmicky to me.

Comment: @Jan in true high-quality printing, the ligature would be f fi.

Answer (score 16):

### photostack.com

This domain is parked.

People know what kind of site it is right away, because:

- *photo* says it's about photography
- *stack* says it's a Stack Overflow Q&A site

Thus, this domain self-documents excellently.

I believe there's tremendous value in identifying the site at a Stack Overflow-type Q&A site, as it's a very high quality interface and people know what to expect and how it works.

Comment: Interestingly, this actually seems to have taken hold with a few folks as an interim way of self-referencing the site. :)

Comment: Association with Stack Overflow would only be useful if all the audience here would know it; and I don't think that is the case

Comment: @Rowland, why does *all* the audience need to know it to gain utility? There's lots of overlap between techies who know Stack Overflow and photographers. Stack Overflow is a great brand. Let's leverage it.

Comment: I like the fact that this specifically calls out photography as opposed to the answers that are generically optical terms (depth-of-field and viewfinder).  Additionally this reads well without hyphenation and is already the natural shortened version of the url: `photo.stackexchange.com`

Comment: Beyond the connection to stackoverflow/stackexchange, there is the idea of a stack of prints, which I feel works well.

Comment: I think photostack.com is the pick of the crop.

Answer (score 13):

## www.viewfinder.com

---

We want to use this site to find (or give) information (views) on photography.

It's currently parked on a generic search engine page.  It's likely that it can be purchased, but probably for a price.

Comment: Only seems to be parked with a redirect to a search/ad page. No real content though, so could possibly be purchasable.

Comment: It could suggest that it is a good sight for discussion of subjective issues. While there is some of that, we don't want to be seen that way.

Comment: Well, it's less subjective than DOF/bokeh in my opinion.

Answer (score 9):

## PhotoQnA.com

I own it and was using it for a StackExchange, back when mere mortals had access. But now we're getting cut off, and photo.se is going to dominate the market. Might as well put it to good use.

Comment: I was on photoqna, and would *love* to see it be this.

Answer (score 5):

### f8.com

which is currently taken, though.

Comment: I like it. A lot of common f-stops could be substituted for 8.

Answer (score 1):

### TackSharp.com

parked

Answer (score 1):

Focused Advice

## FocusedAdvice.com

Available.

Inspired by Food and Cooking's [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name/206#206).

Answer (score 0):

## FStopZero.com

Domain status: **Taken**, but seems to be only parked.

<sub>To [quote Joel](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/): "If it’s available for a reasonable amount of money...we may even be able to buy it."</sub>

Comment: Mathematically impossible from the definition of the f-stop. ;-)

Comment: @Matt: That's the point, although not many seem to like it.

Answer (score -1):

## varyingfocus.com

Its not great, but its something, and currently available

Answer (score -1):

## DarkroomQuestions.com

A little dated in the era of digital photography

Comment: Kind of reminded me of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_room_%28sexuality%29

Comment: reminded me of the former http://darkroom.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hopefully our attempt will not end up like that.

Comment: Seems darkroom.stackexchange now redirects here anyway

Answer (score -1):

**filmoverexposure.com**

Answer (score -1):

I have http://photographr.info for a previous SE site.  It doesn't match Joel's rules, but adding here for completeness, and on the off-chance that people like it.

Answer (score -2):

Photo Complete

## PhotoComplete.com

For Sale, very reasonable.

Answer (score -2):

## **BetterExposure.com**

- Questions reach more people
- Better quality answers
- Increase the chances that your photos are exposed correctly ;)

Answer (score -2):

**Meta: domain should somehow invoke the Stack Overflow brand.**

I believe there's tremendous value in identifying the site at a Stack Overflow-type Q&A site, as it's a very high quality interface and people know what to expect and how it works.

(Some text duplicated from my other answer, but I believe the point is general.)

Comment: Probably worth reading the blog post linked in the question -- one pertinent quote "American audiences, generally, don’t trust series. They tend to believe that they want the best baking book, period, not whatever baking book comes in yellow. When they see a shelf full of yellow dummy books, they mostly say, “yeah, a bunch of second-best books.”". For the record, I'd say it's not just American Audiences

Comment: @Rowland, while that may be true in general, Stack Overflow is a powerful and very highly regarded brand. Let's leverage that value. An FWIW, I think the blog post uses a poor example: of course people are skeptical of For Dummies books. There are zillions of them; you could almost consider them shovelware. What we have in Stack Overflow is a small, highly regarded brand. Additionally, an subtle invoking of the brand is different than calling it photos.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score -2):

### fotostack.com

A variation on *photostack.com*. Harder to read over the phone, but funny spelling makes us more Web 2.0-ey. ;)

This domain appears to be owned by an individual and not used for anything interesting (has default web page from new server install).

Comment: I prefer the correct spelling much more

Answer (score -3):

### MaxDOF.com

(available - surprising!)

Or (all available):

- MaximumDOF.com
- MaxDepthOfField.com
- MaximumDepthOfField.com

Comment: I'd avoid "DOF" as an acronym. Prefixing "Max" (or "Maximum") to "Depth of Field" makes it too long.

Answer (score -3):

**Meta: domain should contain the word *photo***.

Reasoning: it's self-documenting and abundantly clear what the subject matter is. Puns and jargon make the domain less accessible.

Answer (score -5):

shootthem.com - available

Comment: If there's ever a photography equivalent of the "not programming related" stack exchange this would be perfect :) - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related

Answer (score -6):

## SayEnhance.com

Comment: Too much emphasis on editing/manipulation, seems to veer off photography-specific.

Comment: And to add to Roger's comment, there has been very little on editing/manipulation so far...

Answer (score -9):

**PhotoAnswerZ.com**

I own the domain: http://www.photoanswerz.com/
It was supposed to be similar site as photo.stackexchange.com but Joel and Jeff killed that dream :)

I am willing to give this domain to the community if you like it.

Comment: Kinda fails the "can be read out over a phone line" test