# Site Attribute Questions (Top 7)

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes, beta

OK, so as the beta testers we're supposed to work on key aspects of the site's attributes.  Taking a cue from other betas, I've made this list so we can easily find them all.

I've made this a CW so anyone can edit it and change these list items into links when the questions are made.

(Some from the [7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), some from other betas)

- [FAQ (What it should contain)](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-suggestion) - Please tag using `[faq-suggestion]`
- [Domain Name / Site Name](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-the-domain-name-should-be)
- Site Logo / Style
- [Moderators](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174/moderator-nomination-thread)
- [404 Image](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/amusing-404-page-not-found-image)
- [CAPTCHA Image](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/choosing-a-captcha-image)
- What counts as [off topic](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-topic) - please tag using `[off-topic]`
- How do we [promote this site](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203/how-do-we-promote-photo-se)

Thanks for helping out in the beta!

Answer (score 1):

I've just linked the FAQ to the tag search results page here on meta for the `[faq-suggestion]` tag, which we can all use for suggested FAQ items.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious how we can approach the site logo/style topic. What are the options there? Area 51 is pretty flashy compared to the other stackexchange sites. Is it possible to have a more richly designed site, or are we limited to basic color changes and a custom logo?

Comment: The current design is just a template used for all beta sites. When we'll get out of beta (after ~90 days), the site will get a design on its own.

Comment: @che: Right...but how do we go about choosing a design, and what are the limitations around what we can do with our design?

Comment: As I have seen stackoverflow and similar sites, it's probably going to be this layout with some color/graphics changes. However, I have no idea how the design choosing is going to look.

Answer (score 0):

I've created the `[beta]` tag for use on all meta questions to do with the beta-phase, and tagged the existing questions with it.