# Amusing 404 Page Not Found Image?

Tags: discussion, site-attributes, top-7, beta

I don't know if you've noticed, but each SO "Trilogy" site's 404 (Page Not Found Error) has its own on-topic amusing image.  This site currently has the boring "PAGE NOT FOUND :(" that every beta SE site has ([check it out if you don't believe me](https://photo.stackexchange.com/fourohfour)).

So, following the lead of other betas, I'm starting this question to gather ideas for amusing 404 Page Not Found images.

To clarify exactly what we're looking for, here's a quote showing what Jeff was originally looking for [when he asked for ideas on  the SO trilogy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/amusing-404-page-not-found-images-for-trilogy-sites/):

> By on topic, I mean the 404 image on
>   Stack Overflow should be a programmery
>   "not found" of some kind, and the
>   Super User one should be a power
>   user's "not found", and so forth.

So a photography-related "problem" or inside joke for this site would be funny...

More from Jeff (my edit in [brackets]):

> These images would be shown in
>   addition to the existing 404 page
>   text, so nothing is getting lost,
>   we're just trying to inject a little
>   fun into the process.
>
> I'm having trouble coming up with
>   anything. Any good suggestions? Post
>   them as answers!
>
> If your submission or suggestion is
>   highly voted and meets the criteria
>   outlined, it's likely to be deployed
>   as the "official" 404 image for [this site] …

Please post the image AND quote the source so the dev team can negotiate rights if necessary.

[(Vote on other Site Attributes)](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/)

Answer (score 16):

How about:
[http://farm1.static.flickr.com/156/425731394_41727f12fa_z.jpg](/photos/erica_marshall/425731394/) via [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57/downsides-to-using-a-uv-filter/63#63).

It is Creative Commons licensed, and conveniently the copyright holder is apparently a user of the site...

Comment: That's my photo, and I'd be honored (and amused) if it were used on the 404 page for this site!

Comment: Looks like a good option to me!

Comment: Thanks! [This is now live on the 404 page](http://photo.stackexchange.com/404).

Answer (score 11):

[image: Cracked filter]

Source: [pointnshoot on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/pointnshoot/70518248)

Comment: All rights reserved :/

Comment: @che: Indeed. However, something similar would rock. :D I think it demonstrates the concept well.

Comment: And we could always ask...Flickr makes it easy to blanket-license photos so it's possible he would be willing to let us use it.

Comment: well... it's certainly a painful image...

Comment: yes...thankfully it was just the filter that broke.  phew.

Comment: I like the idea but think it is not broken enough: just the filter!

Comment: I was immediately reminded of this set on Flickr: http://www.flickr.com/photos/photophool/sets/72157594232543508/

Comment: Sigh, I KNEW I should have taken a picture of my 50mm lens breaking. Of course, I'd have to think of how to do it without a DSLR, but...

Answer (score 5):

I'd need to go shoot it, but what about the back LCD of a camera with the "no Card Found" message? Or the "no images" one when you try to chimp with an empty card?

---

update with processed shots from  quick trial shoot, a couple candidates:

[image: back display]

[Bigger](http://www.smugmug.com/photos/1213860545_DJoeg-X3.jpg)

[image: top display closeup]

[Bigger](http://www.smugmug.com/photos/1213860627_Y8PWQ-X3.jpg)

I shot it all with a solid white background so the image could just feather into the the background on the 404 page without a border any anything.

and a sneak peak behind the scenes:
[image: back stage]
[image: back stage]

Comment: I like the "No card found message"

Comment: I tried to catch the "NO CF" on the top LCD but the only second camera I have is my cell phone, and I can't do what I want with that one :)  I'd love to see what someone with a real second body could do.

Comment: I'll setup for it next weekend (8 days from now, not 2...) if no one else has by then.

Comment: @drewbenn... ugh, that proved hard, even with a second real body. the stupid thing flashes so quickly that it's only dark for about 1/3 the time... so a long exposure gets gray, an a fast exposure is a hit and miss crap shoot. :/

Comment: @cabbey errrr I guess I could have mentioned that :)  it looks great, though!  Nice touch to include the low-battery indicator.  I especially like how much the end result looks like my 30D.  P.S. thanks for including the setup pictures; it even looks like you have the same tripod I do under your 20D :)

Comment: Wish I could take credit for intentionally having a low battery light on. :) That was pure coincidence, but seems kinda fitting.

Answer (score 4):

Along the lines of Simon's tangle of film, I think a pile of memory cards would be a nice illustration.

Something similar to this (although I don't think we'd have rights to use it...)
[image: memory cards]

SOURCE: [www.ilovememorycards.com](http://www.ilovememorycards.com/as-technology-grows-some-memory-cards-are-becoming-obsolete.html)

Comment: I like this. :) I think it demonstrates the concept perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

[image: ExposedFilm]

I was originally thinking of an image of a massive tangled pile of exposed film, but my google-fu doesn't seem to be good enough to find anything. Perhaps someone else can find something better in the same theme. (Or someone could even shoot their own)

(Source: [evolvingbeauty.com](http://evolvingbeauty.com/index.php/evolving/techPost/35mm/))

Slightly better one:

[image: Pile of exposed film]

(Source: [IStockPhoto.com](http://www.istockphoto.com/file_closeup/arts-and-entertainment/visual-art/8429382-pile-of-exposed-35mm-film.php?id=8429382) - available at high res without the watermark for a sensible price)

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw out one of my own. Although I know that we're probably more focused on DSLRs than P&Ses ... This was actually one of my first DSLR shots, and I moved (and overexposed) ... And wound up liking the effect once I cleaned up the RAW a bit.

It is All Rights Reserved, but I shot it, so I'd grant permission for it to be used here. :) (And I'm authorized to do so!)

[image: Cthulhu got a camera]

Answer (score 1):

Here's my submission (following on from the current theme).

I've given it an open CC licence to do with as you please.

[image: Bust by mattburns.co.uk]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Broken camera]

Source is [Big Stock Photo](http://www.bigstockphoto.com/image-1420805/stock-photo-bad-day&refid=D9fk3hvJXb), if we're going to use it, a small fee would be required (Only a few dollars, so...)