# The 404 not found image is not unique

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This site's `404 not found` image is not unique. It's shared with Web Apps SE and Pro Webmasters SE.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/404
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/404
https://photo.stackexchange.com/404

It's entirely possible that this is intentional, but since most sites don't have the same image, I thought it was reasonable to suspect that it was a bug.

Sister bug reports:
[on Meta Web Apps](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/751/the-404-not-found-image-is-not-unique)
[on Meta Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367/the-404-not-found-image-is-not-unique)

Comment: My guess is that it isn't a bug so much as a TODO item.  Perhaps we should use this thread to propose images to use there.  Something that captures the idea of being lost with a camera perhaps...

Comment: they don't always have to be unique. But I'm always open to suggestions. Feel free to start a thread on meta.photo so we can crowdsource some 404 photos.

Comment: @rowland I missed that for some reason. thanks. I'll update site's 404 image.

Comment: @Jin have you had a chance yet?

Answer (score 2):

There was [a thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13/21) to come up with a unique, brand specific, image. I believe Jin missed this when the initial design was being put together, or there wasn't a clear leader.