# The error page still has the sketchy image

Tags: bug, design

I just hit the error page on the main site and it's still showing the sketchy image:

[image: Sketchy error image]

You can see it in place here:

https://photo.stackexchange.com/error

Shouldn't this be a nice (well you know what I mean) image in keeping with the site theme?

Comment: Now soliciting suggestions.. post possible error images as answers here!

Comment: I suppose what we want is an artistic "fail" photo. Check the one out on DIY - http://diy.stackexchange.com/error

Comment: I thought we had a topic way, way back when this site started, and a bunch of images were submitted. I believe the community back then also selected the one they wanted. Is there a reason that image was not used?

Comment: Here is the original thread with 404 images: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13/amusing-404-page-not-found-image

Comment: @jrista - I missed that. I think that one of those images should be used.

Comment: @jrista Ah thanks, I missed that thread. We'll take a look...

Comment: The 404 page from [that thread](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13/amusing-404-page-not-found-image) is now [live](http://photo.stackexchange.com/404)! Still need a good error image though...

Comment: I dunno, I think that broken-lens image would be better on the error page, and the 404 page should have something that better reflects the concept of "not found"...

Comment: @Martha I kinda agree.. maybe use the something along the lines of [a pile of SD cards](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/a/75/5) for the 404 page?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments (from [Martha](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2612/the-error-page-still-has-the-sketchy-image#comment4826_2612) and [Emmett](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2612/the-error-page-still-has-the-sketchy-image#comment4827_2612) in particular) to the question I think we should have:

1. The current [404 image](https://photo.stackexchange.com/404) (a broken lens) as the error page.
2. [A pile of SD cards](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/75/441) as the 404 page.