# Choosing a CAPTCHA Page Image

Tags: discussion, site-attributes, top-7, captcha, beta

We need to choose a CAPTCHA image.

To clarify, what we're looking for is an amusing picture to go on the CAPTCHA page...along with the CAPTCHA. The image will just be for added comedic effect; it won't be the CAPTCHA itself (the CAPTCHA is from reCAPTCHA). Check out the "HELLO FELLOW ROBOT" image on the current captcha page: [photo.stackexchange.com/captcha](https://photo.stackexchange.com/captcha)

I'm not entirely sure what would demonstrate the idea of a CAPTCHA well, however I recently took an image that I called "Contemplation" that might fit the bill.

It would be interesting if we could find an image that visually demonstrated the idea of a CAPTCHA. Hopefully someone has a much better image than mine, as it is rather obscure:

[Contemplation http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/182/8/0/8031430db6cb59d4911c32994cdc5d6c.jpg](http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/182/8/0/8031430db6cb59d4911c32994cdc5d6c.jpg)

[Copyright © 2010 Jon Rista]

Comment: Please CW this.

Answer (score 13):

I did a google image search for robot camera and found this:

[image: robot camera]

I guess we'd have to ask [Russel "oddbot"](http://letsmakerobots.com/user/1533) (who wrote the [original post](http://letsmakerobots.com/node/5027)) for permission to use it. The post has comments and the poster seems to be pretty active, so if this image is popular we could leave a comment on the post to ask for permission to use it. I couldn't see another way to send that user a message, but maybe if you register for the site there will be some way to contact them directly.

Comment: Ha! This is GREAT!

Comment: Fits well with the CAPTCHA context.

Answer (score 3):

The [Robot II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_II) was a mechanical 135 film camera by Robot introduced in 1938.

[image: Robot II Camera]

The image is from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Robot_mp3h0297.jpg) and has a CC-BY-SA license.

However the robot link might be a bit obscure, and the Robot logo is not that obvious.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Robot made from camera]

Robot sculpted by [Andrea Petrachi Himatic](http://www.andreapetrachi.com/portfolio_______________.html). Photo by Guiseppe Fogarizzu from [here](http://twistedsifter.com/2010/04/robotic-sculptures-by-andrea-petrachi-himatic/). Permission would need to be obtained.

Answer (score 1):

I think the photobooth can convey the notion of robots well in our field, so we can use something like this:
[image]
(public domain picture from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Fotofix_booth_2005.jpg))

Another option would be a camera on a tripod with figurine holding "please smile" sign, but I guess it would be difficult to find such image unless someone is willing to shoot it.

Answer (score 0):

How does either of these pictures work as a [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA)? CAPTCHA is used as a system to identify automated bots spaming sites. Breaking through a CAPTCHA that displays the same static image at all times is rather trivial.

Comment: I'm not sure the question expresses this properly--what we're looking for is an amusing picture to go on the CAPTCHA page...along with the CAPTCHA.  The image will just be for added comedic effect; it won't be the CAPTCHA itself.  Check out the "HELLO FELLOW ROBOT" image on the current captcha page: http://photo.stackexchange.com/captcha  I edited the question to reflect this.  Also, please note that your comment would be better suited as a comment than as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and yes it would be better suited as a comment