# Moderator nomination thread

Tags: discussion, site-attributes, top-7, moderators

Per [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) blog post, we should somehow get together moderator nominations for our site.

> About a week into the public beta, we will seek out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:
>
> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Some other rules:

> - Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
> - The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
> - Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. (...) Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

Comment: +1 - I read that blog post last night, but it was way past bed time so I figured I'd create this post in the morning (if nobody else had done it already). I updated the "Top 7 Site Attribute Questions" post (http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11/site-attribute-questions-top-7) to point here.

Comment: I'll start the ball rolling then :)

Comment: I think it would also be useful for nominators to say briefly why they are nominating a particular person.

Comment: Do we need a total of 4 moderators? Was wondering who else we might nominate...there are still some avid users on the main site who have shown dedication and extensive knowledge.

Comment: Good to see that you've accepted the nominations! You are all very active and provide good answers (and critical comments). Good luck! :)

Comment: This is going to seem like a silly question, but I'm curious as to why this is on the meta site and not on the main site? Not that it matters to me, I voted anyways, but I would think a large portion of the community would miss this.

Comment: Ah, never mind, I think I figured out the answer to my question. That's what happens when you're too busy to join in the beta phase and miss all the interesting things. ;)

Answer (score 11):

[Jrista](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/124/jrista) (accepted nomination)

Thank you for the nomination, I'm honored.

Comment: Jrista has a lot of technical knowledge while still accepting corrections.  He would be a valuable moderator

Answer (score 9):

[Rowland Shaw](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/21/rowland-shaw) (accepted nomination)

Comment: I think Rowland has provided some excellent answers to important questions. He has also asked some important questions that I think help build the community baseline. His experience dates back several decades, and I think he brings a good, solid background to the table.

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence -- don't forget to indicate whether you accept or decline the nomination of yourself...

Comment: @Rowland: I'm still thinking about my nomination. ;) I appreciate it very much...but I am not sure I am really qualified enough as a photographer.

Comment: being a skilled photographer is not the primary requirement for being a moderator (as mentioned elsewhere in comments).

Comment: Sure, I was one of the people who made those comments. However, my knowledge is almost purely theoretical/technical, as I've only had about 1 year of actual photography experience. But, it sounds like people think I'll be valuable, so I'll accept.

Answer (score 8):

[Guffa](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/149/guffa) (accepted nomination)

Comment: I thought I would throw in a good word for Guffa. He has shown thorough knowledge of photography, both digital and film. His knowledge seems to span both the theoretical and the practical application.

Answer (score 3):

Would it be dreadfully rude to ask prospective mods a bit about their photographic background?  Perhaps not for the pro-tem mods (though I'd like that), but what about the more-permanent ones?

I don't ask because I think we need an MFA or something on the mod team, but rather because I think there's a bonus to diversity in background and experience, and I think there's a good chance we might miss out on that, given the founding bias of SO users (though it's **very** hard to say for sure, people's profiles are so brief).

I should add (per comments) that I'm assuming we'll pick community-minded people first, and again given the founding set of users, we're probably quite well off in that respect.  Having a variety of perspectives within that group is what I'd think of as the ideal situation, and why not aim high?

Because it **would** be rude to ask for something I wouldn't provide, myself, briefly: I'm a programmer.  I've been doing photography seriously for 15 years, but with no particular qualifications apart from some darkroom printing workshops.  I shoot film almost exclusively, favour street and documentary photography, and tend to read about the art/philosophy side of modern photography.  And no, I wouldn't pick myself as a mod. ;)

Comment: IMHO, Moderation isn't just about knowledge of the field -- it's more about building the community, and understanding how to get the most out of the software the site uses.

Comment: @matt good reminder to tidy up profiles, and tailor them to each site they use.

Comment: @matt: should we also take this as a nomination for moderator?

Comment: @Rowland - yes, I absolutely agree.  I'd assumed we'd get that aspect right.  I'll add it to the entry so people don't have to parse the comments.

Comment: @Fredrik: No. Like I said, I wouldn't pick myself, it'd be silly to nominate myself. :)

Comment: I think its ok to ask prospective mods about their background. While I think we need people who understand how the stackexchange software works, so they can be effective at moderating, the site does have a specific target audience, and it would be helpful to have community leaders to know the field. I don't think every candidate needs to know everything...specialists in one thing or another are perfectly ok.

Comment: I'd say one of the most important attributes of the moderator is scientific approach to knowledge - what are the facts, what are just opinions and beliefs, what we know, what we don't know and what we don't know that we don't know.

Comment: I think the idea of aiming for balance is a great one. We want moderators to cover knowing the SE software, being good on the community side, knowing about photography, cameras and post-processing ... We don't need every moderator to cover all of those areas, but between them they should cover them all.

Answer (score 2):

<s>[Matt Smillie](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/496/matt-smillie)</s> (Appreciated, but declined.)

Comment: Thank you both, but like I joked-but-serious above, moderation is not my cup of tea, as I have trouble applying it in moderation.  :)

Comment: Sorry to hear that, Matt. ;) Good to have you around, though...you have a lot of good knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>[Reid Priedhorsky](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/27/reid-priedhorsky)</strike> (Declined nomination - see comment below)

Comment: I think Reid has shown a remarkable breadth of knowledge, and has offered some of the most helpful answers on this site so far. I think he deserved a nomination. :)

Comment: Thanks for the nomination, and I'm honored; however, I must decline for the present - I'm currently finishing up my Ph.D. and don't have enough brainspace to give the task the attention it deserves. :) If there's another round of nominations a few months down the road, I'd be happy to be reconsidered.

Comment: @Reid for the record, it was your question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/staying-inspired-during-periods-of-distraction which implied you wouldn't have the time, which is why I hadn't put you in my original three...

Comment: @Rowland, no worries - you're one step ahead of me.

Comment: @Reid: Sorry, I wasn't as observant as Reid. I didn't catch that you were already swamped. Best of luck with your Ph.D!

Comment: Thanks! I defend in just under a month and have a great job lined up after that, so there's light at the end of the tunnel.