# "Photographic Editing" in the site name

Tags: discussion, site-attributes

When digital age people talk about "photographic editing" then they usually mean manipulating the image in Photoshop or similar software, while the older generation perceives this as choosing photos/guiding the creative process/etc. Think about what a magazine Photo Editor does. So I suggest the better tagline for the site would be Photography and Photo Manipulation (just Image Manipulation would be a little too generic, while Photographic Image Manipulation is too long).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site name itself will probably change with the domain name.  [See the discussion on that question here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-the-domain-name-should-be).